# OnProductPurchased Does not called after Purchasing Subscription

Tags: in-app-purchase, runtime-error, in-app-billing

Can anybody help me to solve this 102 error?

I used Anjlab V3 library in my android app. I am testing with the same developer account on which my app is live that provided with me free testing cards. When I subscribed to subscription then in my actiivty `onActivityResult` Mehtod is called but after that `OnBillingError` method callback is received rather than `onProductPurchased`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: *OnBillingError Method is called rather than OnProductPurchased method

Comment: Can you share [the code that caused the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full error message?